# Why lombok adding canEqual method

Tags: java, equals, lombok

When using lombok [@Data](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) (which adds [EqualsAndHashCode](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode))

It adds `canEqual` method

> ```
> protected boolean canEqual(Object other) {
>   return other instanceof Exercise;
> }
> ```

which is only called once:

> ```
> if (!other.canEqual((Object)this)) return false;
> ```

I search and found [discussions](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/project-lombok/QiLSjxpXpKs/75tPKV8EdRwJ) about access level

> If you implement equals and hashCode in a non-final class the safest thing we can do is add the can equal the way we do. Since we don't add any field the costs, especially if the method is protected, are slim.

But why do we need this generated method ? can't it be inline?

Comment: The purpose of not-inlining it is so that it can be overridden.

Comment: @chrylis lombok code is pretty minimized, what is the common/real use case for adding it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `canEqual` method is defined in a paper entitled [How to Write an Equality Method in Java](https://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html). This method is meant for allowing to redefine equality on several levels of the *class hierarchy* while keeping its contract:

> The idea is that as soon as a class redefines `equals` (and `hashCode`), it should also explicitly state that objects of this class are never equal to objects of some superclass that implement a different equality method. This is achieved by adding a method `canEqual` to every class that redefines `equals`.

---

Seems like it was introduced in Lombok 0.10, as described in the [`@EqualsAndHashCode`](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode) documentation:

> *NEW in Lombok 0.10:* Unless your class is `final` and extends `java.lang.Object`, lombok generates a `canEqual` method which means JPA proxies can still be equal to their base class, but subclasses that add new state don't break the equals contract.

And the documentation goes a bit further, referencing the paper quoted above:

> The complicated reasons for why such a method is necessary are explained in this paper: [How to Write an Equality Method in Java](https://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html). If all classes in a hierarchy are a mix of scala case classes and classes with lombok-generated equals methods, all equality will 'just work'. If you need to write your own `equals` methods, you should always override `canEqual` if you change `equals` and `hashCode`.

Comment: But what is the common/real use case? it should be common use case if lombok implemented it, no?

Comment: @user7294900 From the best of my knowledge, it's mainly (possibly only) use case is allowing the redefinition equality in a class hierarchy while keeping its contract.

Comment: Thanks, would it be wrong if I don't override the canEqual() method... InteliJ refactor generates that code.... example..  protected boolean canEqual(final Object other) {  return other instanceof Currency; }

Comment: @Jay yes, it would be wrong - the linked paper explains that without it, you break the symmetry-requirement when redefining equality in a subclass, making `equals` not an equivalence relation in your codebase (which may trigger weird problems...)

Comment: Of course redefining equality in a subclass breaks the contract. It violates the LSP. The paper acknowledges this, and then tries to downplay it. Using their ColoredPoint example in the paper, if I define a Line class that takes to Points to create one, and the creation verifies the two Points are not equal, I can break the Line contract by using a ColoredPoint and a Point at the same coordinate to create a Line which the Line creation will think are not equal.